# How to implement Session Management on SQL Azure in 2016?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-web-app-service

I am using Asp.net MVC 5 on Azure websites and SQL Azure.

I have specified 2016 in the question, as I am aware of many outdated approaches.

How can I setup the SQL Azure schema? Trying to locate the script files.

Am I mistaken in using this mode, or should I be using Redis or Table Storage. Redis is obviously quite expensive, around £65 per month for cheapest 99.9% SLA option.

Thanks.

**EDIT 1**

It looks like MS no longer supports session management in SQL Azure, see: [MS Article](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/blog/using-sql-azure-for-session-state/)

As far as I understand they recommend only using Azure Redis caching. Am I correct? I am very surprised one cannot use SQL Azure. I know it may be a little slower, but it would be straightforward and reliable.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you should use Azure Redis. I'm not sure why sql would be more straightforward than using Redis. Using Redis is as simple as pulling in the nuget project and making the addition to the web.config to configure the session state provider as your azure Redis instance you have created. From there you can start using the Redis libraries.

```
 <sessionState mode="Custom" customProvider="RedisSessionProvider">
  <providers>
    <add name="RedisSessionProvider" 
         type="Microsoft.Web.Redis.RedisSessionStateProvider" 
         port="6380" 
         host="YOURCACHE.cache.windows.net"
         accessKey="Primary Access Key" ssl="true" />
  </providers>
</sessionState>

public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        object value = Session["Home"];
        int result = 0;
        if (value != null)
        {
            result = (int)value;
            Session["Home"] = ++result;
        }
        else
        {
            Session["Home"] = 1;
        }

        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult About()
    {
        object value = Session["Home"];
        string home = "Didn't work";
        if(value != null)
        {
            home = ((int)value).ToString();
        }
        ViewBag.Message = string.Format("The cache value is {0}", home);

        return View();
    }
}
```

[Here's a link](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-dotnet-session-state-caching/) on how.

Comment: Thank you for this. I am testing this out. However any ideas how to setup SQL Azure as the session provider. The install scripts seemed to have disappeared. Is using SQL Azure a big no, no?

Comment: Interestingly I have had no end of issues trying to create an Azure Redis Cache. I keep getting ServerTimeOut errors. I have tried on the Northern Europe and Western Europe Data centre. Seems to take a long time, then fail. How long should creating a Redis Cache take?

Comment: Our Redis deployments did work in the end, just took a long time, around an hour.

Comment: The link above talks above about Session.Add, but even with the addition of "using StackExchange.Redis;", I still get a "Name session does not exist in current context. Basically it cannot find "Session".

Comment: While studying for my Developing Azure solutions certification the documentation always read to use Redis for session management and didn't indicate another path was supported. They may no longer support using Azure sql for session management which could be why it's so hard to find documentation on it. I certainly haven't been able to find any.

Comment: Where are you trying to use session? Are you getting a compile time or run time error?

Comment: You don't need to have the using statement. You're setting up the default HttpSessionStateBase session to use the azure Redis cache. I just tried it on an example application and verified it works. Post your sessionState config as well as your code where you use session state please

Comment: @SamJolly I added my sample code from example application I tested on

Comment: Thank you for this. Very helpful. We did find that "System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["CurrentUser"]" did the trick, and the Redis cache was finally created. One of the strange thing I have noticed is a huge amount of gets and sets, and a large amount of storage being used, especially as I am just developing and testing. Do I assume that the Cache gets released automatically when the session expires like "inproc" session does?

Comment: Yes I believe so. The default timeout was 1200 seconds from what I saw. If you're curious about what's getting stored in Redis etc. like I was then I would suggest using this Redis browser http://redisdesktop.com. I couldn't get it to connect to the Azure Redis cache from my Windows machine but it did work for my Mac.